# AudioUnitInitialize failed with error code 1852008051

Tags: ios, ios5, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to record with Audio Unit in iOS.
I set componentSubType in AudioComponentDescription to **kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO**.
Then both of AudioUnitInitialize and AudioOutputUnitStart's error code is **1852008051('ncfs')**.
I cannot find this error code in the document.
But when I turn **kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO** to  **kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO**, everything is just fine.
Could anyone tell me what should be modified when changing from VoiceProcessingIO to RemoteIO?

Comment: I had some issues when switching to `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO`, see my self-answered SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821404/apples-voice-processing-audio-unit-kaudiounitsubtype-voiceprocessingio-brok/12856322#12856322

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to record from the device, then you need to use the remote IO component subtype, and then set this property:

```
UInt32 flag = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(yourAudioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &flag, sizeof(flag));
```

You also might find this tutorial about use of [remote IO audio units](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) helpful.