# Apple's Voice Processing Audio Unit ( kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO ) broken on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, audiounit

I'm writing a VOIP app for iPad (currently targeting 2&3).

I originally wrote the audio code using the Audio Unit API, with a kAudioUnitSubtype_RemoteIO unit. This worked well, but unsurprisingly echo was a problem. I tried to use the built-in echo-suppression by switching to using a kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO unit. This works really well on iOS 6 (iPad 3), but the same code on iOS 5.1 (iPad 2) produces white noise on the microphone input.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO) just mentions that it should be available in iOS 3.0 and later

The iOS version seems to be the important difference here. I tried running the app on two iPhone 4Ss, one with iOS 6 which sounded fine and one with iOS 5.1 which sounded like white noise.

My ASBD looks like this:

```
typedef int16_t sample_t;
#define AUDIO_BUFFER_SAMPLE_RATE 48000
#define FORMAT_FLAGS (kAudioFormatFlagsIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsIsNonInterleaved)
#define CHANNELS_PER_FRAME 1

...

const size_t bytes_per_sample = sizeof(sample_t);
const int eight_bits_per_byte = 8;
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamFormat.mSampleRate = AUDIO_BUFFER_SAMPLE_RATE;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags = FORMAT_FLAGS;

streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = CHANNELS_PER_FRAME;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = bytes_per_sample * CHANNELS_PER_FRAME;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = bytes_per_sample * eight_bits_per_byte;

streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame * streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
streamFormat.mReserved = 0;
```

Has anyone ever got kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO to work on iOS 5.1?

Does anyone know of any serious documentation for this IO?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR add `kAudioFormatFlagsIsPacked` to `FORMAT_FLAGS`

I discovered this via a bit of a convoluted route. None of this seems to be well documentated anywhere, but I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792469/how-to-use-kaudiounitsubtype-voiceprocessingio-subtype-of-core-audio-api-in-ma) talking about using the IO on a Mac. One of the things mentioned was using "FlagsCononical". I tried setting:

```
#define FORMAT_FLAGS kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical
```

which didn't work, and the call to AudioUnitInitialize failed with a return code of 29759. I couldn't find any documentation about what this meant, but when I tried:

```
#define FORMAT_FLAGS kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical
```

everything worked! Success!

The definition of `kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical` in CoreAudioTypes.h if you are building for an iPad (and therefore have `CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT` defined as `1`) is:

```
kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical = kAudioFormatFlagsIsSignedInteger
                           | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian
                           | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
```

After adding `kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked` to my original code it worked. I added `kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian` for good measure. I removed `kAudioFormatFlagsIsNonInterleaved` as it was unnecessary for single channel audio anyway. What I was left with is identical to `kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical`.

So my set-up, which worked on an iPad 2 (iOs 5.1) and an iPad 3 (iOS 6.0) was the following:

- Sample rate of `48000`
- 1 channel
- `kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical`
- `int16_t` samples
- Linear PCM

I'm still keen on documentation for this IO if anyone has any.