# AEC ( Echo Cancellation Support ) in OSX Using AudioQueue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, audioqueue, echo-cancellation

I am developing VOIP Application on OSX and iOS and will be using AudioQueue for Audio flow, what want to Know is, by default does AudioQueue support acoustic echo cancellation or do we need to add support for it,
If we need to implement, i believe some open source library has to be implemented like Speex are there any Example available shows integration of AudioQueue with Speex or any other library

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I am having the same question.

Answer (score 21):

As far as I can find, you have to use Audio Units to access the system's echo cancellation. You do that by using [`kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/UsingSpecificAudioUnits/UsingSpecificAudioUnits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH17-SW1) instead of  `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO`.

You probably want to use Audio Units anyway, in order to control your latency.

You can use a render callback function to get data from an Audio Queue and pass it to your I/O unit. For outgoing, use `AudioUnitRender`.

Comment: The Voice Processing IO unit is available on 10.7 or later: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007291

Comment: i am on latest OSX Sdk and set the VoiceProcessingIO but still Echo is coming, any solutions

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472761/1669634) and [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821404/apples-voice-processing-audio-unit-kaudiounitsubtype-voiceprocessingio-brok), I have realized following changes are required for Echo Cancellation on iOS:

```
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO
```

This will enable hardware Echo suppression according to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/UsingSpecificAudioUnits/UsingSpecificAudioUnits.html). However, you still need to use specific flags for AudioStream description:

```
audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
```