# AudioUnit Echo Cancellation Built-in Feature for iOS

Tags: ios, audiounit, echo-cancellation

Currently I am developing an iOS app that captures the sound using iPad mic. At the same time, a sound is being played through iPad speakers. Since the objective is to process the isolated input sound, the speaker feedback should be removed (cancelled). I looked for some documentation related to AudioToolbox possibilities. I found out AudioUnit can perform Built-in Features such as echo cancellation. However, I did not manage to configure correctly my audio graph in order to achieve a successful performance.

I would appreciate any suggestion, sample codes, references to tutorials or recommended bibliography.

Thank you very much,

Carles

Comment: I think your answer can be found at the link below. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472761/1184525

Comment: Thanks!!! This was a great help