# Echo Cancellation Support in iOS Using AudioQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, audiounit, audioqueue, echo-cancellation

I need to delete the echo noise within my audio signal.

To create the communication channel I used `AudioQueue` for my app as reported in the `AQRecorder` class from the SpeakHere: https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/SpeakHere/Classes

Now the problem is to delete echo with the function `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` as suggest in [AEC ( Echo Cancellation Support ) in OSX Using AudioQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471018/aec-echo-cancellation-support-in-osx-using-audioqueue/15472761#15472761).

**How convert AudioQueue in AudioUnit?** I need real code example.

Comment: You can't use voice processing with AudioQueues.  They are too slow.  You have to use Audio Units for your communication if you want voice processing.

Comment: This is already clear. For software requirements, I need to use AudioQueue.

What I'm looking for, as mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471018/aec-echo-cancellation-support-in-osx-using-audioqueue/15472761#15472761, is an example of a passage from AudioQueue to AudioUnit, which should be through a render callback function. The main reason for this request is to use echo suppression on an AudioQueue.